# AlarmManager setExact in Android 5.1

Tags: android, alarmmanager

From [Optimizing for Doze and App Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#assessing_your_app):

> Doze is particularly likely to affect activities that AlarmManager
>   alarms and timers manage, because alarms in Android 5.1 (API level 22)
>   or lower do not fire when the system is in Doze.
>
> To help with scheduling alarms, Android 6.0 (API level 23) introduces
>   two new AlarmManager methods: setAndAllowWhileIdle() and
>   setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(). With these methods, you can set alarms
>   that will fire even if the device is in Doze.

So what do I do if I need to set an alarm for an exact time, even during Doze, in Android 5.1? Is it not possible?

Here is my code

```
if (noPreciseTime) {
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now + interval, pendingIntent)
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent)
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent)
} else {
    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So what do I do if I need to set an alarm for an exact time, even during Doze, in Android 5.1?

Devices running 5.1 do not doze, so you need not worry about that. This

```
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent)
```

will work as expected in 5.1. The newer setExactAndAllowWhileIdle was introduced for use on devices running 6.0+. Your code snippet is ok.

> alarms in Android 5.1 (API level 22) or lower do not fire when the system is in Doze

This is a bit of a confusing statement. What they mean to say here is *alarms **set using the 5.1 or lower API's** (like setExact) do not fire when a device is in doze*.

Comment: `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` is the right api to use, also don't forget to register the broadcast in manifest (I figured it out quite late)

Answer (score 0):

In my experiment, AlarmManagerCompat + setAlarmClock is stable to wake up in doze mode. I use xiaomi device which use MIUI.

```
AlarmManagerCompat.setAlarmClock(alarmManager, time, showIntent, pendingIntent)
```